# Duplicate Top Drop Down Menu in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, navigation, top-link-bar

My development environment is SharePoint 2010. I am trying to achieve Drop Down enabled Top Navigation menu.Though my site is showing the top menu but the sub menus are not showing up as drill down but they open up as a sub site on clicking on the static level menu. I have tried the "Navigation" settings under Look and Feel and checking "Show Sub sites and Show Pages" checkboxes. What it does is replicate my whole menu.

Please advice.

Thanks
Vivek b

Answer (score 1):

once go throw this below links you will get more idea about custom top navigation and where you have to modify changes in master page.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/3b3dc6a5-4025-46f5-a575-9b07f378975b

http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2011/08/29/sharepoint-2010-navigation-flyouts-menus/

http://sp2010.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think "Look and Feel" has to do with SharePoint 2007. We must just click on "Show subsites" checkbox under "Global Naviagation".

Comment: I tried that but it duplicates my menu instead of Drop Downs.